# Unmarshalling of nested json results in null values

Tags: json, go, struct, slice, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshal a nested json. The value of one key is an array of jsons. The data looks like this:

```
jsonData := `{"Key0": 1,
                            "Key1": [
                                {"SubKey0": "Id0", "SubKey1": 0, "SubKey2": "rndm0"},   
                                {"SubKey1": "Id1", "SubKey1": 1, "SubKey2": "rndm1"}
                                ]
             }'
```

The number of elements in the array is unkown und variable.

The goal is to get a structure, which contains the data of the array:

I tried the following code:

```
            package main

            import (
                "encoding/json"
                "fmt"
            )

            type Container struct {
                Key0 int
                Key1 []string
            }

            var container Container

            func main() {
                jsonData := `{"Key0": 1,
                            "Key1": [
                                {"SubKey0": "string0", "SubKey1": 0},   
                                {"SubKey0": "string1", "SubKey1": 1}
                                ]
                            }`
                json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &container)
                fmt.Printf(string(container.Key0))
                fmt.Printf(fmt.Sprint(container.Key1))
            }
```

But this results in the container.Key1 being an empty array.

Comment: You're ignoring the error returned by `json.Unmarshal`. And your types are wrong, it should be `Key1 []map[string]interface{}` or a struct instead of map if you know all the field names.

Answer (score 3):

`"Key0"` in JSON is a number, not a `string`.

`"Key1"` in JSON is an array of objects, it's not an array of `string`.

So use this Go struct to model your JSON:

```
type Container struct {
    Key0 int
    Key1 []map[string]interface{}
}
```

Parsing the JSON:

```
jsonData := `{"Key0": 1,
                        "Key1": [
                            {"SubKey0": "string0", "SubKey1": 0},   
                            {"SubKey0": "string1", "SubKey1": 1}
                            ]
                        }`
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &container); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(container.Key0)
fmt.Println(container.Key1)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nlTjKv6Q0WR)):

```
1
[map[SubKey0:string0 SubKey1:0] map[SubKey0:string1 SubKey1:1]]
```